# Applying a series of functions to a list

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I have numerous functions each with arguments:

```
mul = lambda lst, val: [i * val for i in lst]
add = lambda lst, val1, val2: [i + val1 + val2 for i in lst]
...
```

I would like to create a higher-order function that can take any number of functions, each with a variable number of arguments and then apply these function in order to the list. It might look something like this:

```
>>> functions([mul, (10)], [add, (10, 100)]
[120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170]
```

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
mul = lambda lst, val: [i * val for i in lst]
add = lambda lst, val1, val2: [i + val1 + val2 for i in lst]

def functions(lst, *fns):
    for fn, args in fns:
        lst = fn(lst, *args)
    return lst

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
result = functions(lst, [mul, (10,)], [add, (10, 100)])
print result
```

produces:

```
[120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170]
```

You might like to structure the functions differently:

```
mul = lambda i, val: i * val
add = lambda i, val1, val2: i + val1 + val2

def functions(lst, *fns):
    for fn, args in fns:
        lst = [fn(i, *args) for i in lst]
    return lst
```

And as others point out: numpy is designed to do all this and much much more.

Comment: One obvious way, I guess. :^)

Comment: Thanks Ned. This is exactly what I want to do. In my actual use case, using NumPy is not possible. Many thanks for all you do—especially for helping me with Unicode!

Answer (score 4):

Use [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), chained.  E.g.,

```
from functools import partial

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

mul = lambda lst, val: [i * val for i in lst]
add = lambda lst, val1, val2: [i + val1 + val2 for i in lst]

mul10 = partial(mul, val=10)
add_10_100 = partial(add, val1 = 10, val2 = 100)
print add_10_100(mul10(lst))

[120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170]
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide an example for how I can use it?

Comment: This would be better with `reduce`: `reduce(lambda lst,f: f(lst), [partial(mul,val=10), partial(add,val1=10,val2=100)], range(1,7))`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing `numpy`, use it!

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.arange(1, 7)
print lst * 10 + 10 + 100
[120 130 140 150 160 170]
```