# Apply a series of functions to some arguments

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm after something a little more elegant than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703336/applying-a-series-of-functions-to-a-list).

What is the most elegant way to implement F such that:

`F(a,b,c,d,e)` -> `lambda args: a(b(c(d(e(*args)))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `reduce`: maybe something like:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), [a, b, c, d, e], initial_value)
```

Comment: shouldn't your list be in reverse?

Comment: `y(x)` is not a function composition. I think it should be `reduce(lambda f, g: lambda *args: f(g(*args)), [a, b, c, d, e])`.

Comment: @nymk x is the previous (partial) value, y is the current function to be applied...

Comment: @fortran as given it still isn't equivalent to function composition, as the functions are applied in the incorrect order. nymk's solution also happens to be shorter and cleaner IMO.

Comment: @fortran You're right. Then it should be `reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), [e, d, c, b, a], initial_value)`. Furthermore, in this method, `e` must take exactly one argument.

Comment: I think this is our winner!

Comment: @SalimFadhley This won't work on lambdas which take more than one argument. i.e `lambda n,m: (n + m, n ** n)`

Comment: @HennyH The question implied that wasn't a requirement

Comment: @AlexChamberlain How so? If anything it seems the opposite, as `e` accepted multiple arguments, it *could* follow that the other lambdas do to.

Comment: Yes, that was not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = lambda n: n + 2
b = lambda n: n * 2
def F(*funcs):
    def G(*args):
        res = funcs[-1](*args)
        for f in funcs[-2::-1]:
            res = f(res)
        return res
    return G

>>> F(a, b)(1)
4
```

Or better with `reduce` like @DanielRoseman

```
def F(*funcs):
    def G(*args):
        return reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), funcs[-2::-1], funcs[-1](*args))
    return G

>>> F(a, b)(1)
4
```

You could even do it in a single line but I feel like it's less elegant:

```
def F(*funcs):
  return lambda *args: reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), funcs[-2::-1], funcs[-1](*args))
```

Comment: `a(b(1))` returns `4`, not `6`. I think your function is doing `b(a(1))`.

Comment: There is an error in your answer: `b(1) = 2` and `a(2) = 4` therefore `F(a, b)(1)` should be `4`, not `6`. Your function is not applying `a(b(*args))` but `a(b(b(*args)))`

Comment: @Volatility oops should have had `[-2::-1]` start index

Answer (score 1):

This works with *multiple* input values so you can have lambdas which all take `N` paramters, and return `N` values.

```
def F(*funcs):
    def _(*arg):
        if len(arg) ==  1:
            arg = arg[0]
            for f in reversed(funcs):
                arg = f(arg)
        else:
            for f in reversed(funcs):
                arg = f(*arg)
        return arg
    return _
```

Test (multiple):

```
a = lambda n,m: (n + m,m)
b = lambda n,m: (n*m,n)
print(F(a,b)(1,2))
>>> 
(3, 1)
```

Test (single):

```
a = lambda n: n + n
b = lambda n: n ** 2
print(F(a,b)(1))
>>> 
2
```